# Is there a Smalltalk way to transposing an Array?

Tags: collections, smalltalk, transpose, pharo

Suppose I have an array which looks like this

```
{ { #a . #b . #c } . 
  { #e . #f . #g } }.
```

Is there a quick way to turn this into

```
 { { #a . #e } . { #b . #f } . { #c . #g } }
```

the code should work for n-element subarrays too.

```
{ { #a . #b . #c . #d } . 
  { #e . #f . #g . #h } }.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

General purpose one liner, no assumptions about column or row count.

```
(1 to: rows first size) collect: [:column | rows collect: [:row | row at: column]]
```

Some Smalltalk's even implement:

```
SequenceableCollection>>keys
    ^1 to: self size
```

In that case the first can be even nicer implemented as:

```
 rows first keys collect: [:column | rows collect: [:row | row at: column]]
```

Answer (score 4):

```
{ #a . #b . #c } with: { #e . #f . #g } collect: [ :each1 :each2 | { each1 . each2 } ]
```

will give you

```
#(#(#a #e) #(#b #f) #(#c #g))
```

Answer (score 3):

Not quite elegant but it works for collections of any size in almost every Smalltalk:

```
| results input |
input := { { #a . #b . #c } . 
  { #e . #f . #g } }.
results := Array new: input first size.
1 to: results size do: [ : subIndex | 
    results at: subIndex put: (input collect: [ : sub | sub at: subIndex ]) ].
results
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are dealing with matrices, I would suggest creating the Matrix class along with this instance creation method (class side):

```
Matrix class >> fromBlock: aBlock numRows: n columns: m
    | matrix |
    matrix := self newRows: n columns: m.
    1 to: n do: [:i |
        1 to: m do: [:j | | aij |
            aij := aBlock value: i value: j.
            matrix atRow: i column: j put: aij]].
    ^matrix
```

Then, given a matrix you would transpose it using this method (instance side):

```
Matrix >> transposed
    ^self class
        fromBlock: [:i :j | self atRow: j column: i]
        numRows: self numColumns
        columns: self numRows
```